# Changing the default k9s/Kubernetes context

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I have 3 contexts set up in k9s (`context1`, `context2`, `context3`). I know I can change the context within k9s by typing `:context` but how do I change the default context that loads when I open k9s from `context3` to `context1`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the default context via `kubectl`:

```
kubectl config use-context context1
```

This will update the default context in your KUBECONFIG, what is the base for k9s.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the k9s config.yml file, this link can help you understand better [https://k9scli.io/topics/config](https://k9scli.io/topics/config/), normally it is defined like this example:

```
k9s:
  refreshRate: 2
  maxConnRetry: 5
  enableMouse: false
  headless: false
  logoless: false
  crumbsless: false
  readOnly: false
  noExitOnCtrlC: false
  noIcons: false
  logger:
    tail: 100
    buffer: 5000
    sinceSeconds: 60
    fullScreenLogs: false
    textWrap: false
    showTime: false
  **currentContext**: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:ID:cluster/account-name
  **currentCluster**: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:ID:cluster/account-name
```